# Animated circle stroke on svg base don scroll position is not working on mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I'm trying to resolve some disparities in my page elements between how they appear and function on mobile browsers and how they operate in the desktop browser mobile previews.

From a user perspective there is a circle progress bar which has it's stroke length filled in based on a matching percentage text.

The text of the SVG is changing and updating on mobile, tracking the scroll progress of the page as a percentage of the page located in the center of the svg.

But the animated path stroke of the progress bar is not changing as anticipated.

Additionally, in Safari and Chrome on my iPhone 12 the fixed position of the entire SVG element is not set correctly in relation to the right and bottom fixed pixel instructions.

Here is the link to the page https://www.naturalreliefclub.com/magnesium-reviews.html

Here is the HTML:

```
      <svg
        viewbox="0 0 36 36"
        class="circular-chart"
        xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
      >
        <path
          class="circle-bg"
          d="M18 2.0845
            a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 31.831
            a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 -31.831"
        />
        <path
          class="circle"
          stroke-dasharray="0, 100"
          d="M18 2.0845
            a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 31.831
            a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 -31.831"
        />
        <text x="20" y="20.35" class="percentage">0%</text>
      </svg>
```

Here is the CSS

```
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: fixed;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  z-index: 9;
}

.circular-chart {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 75px;
}

.circle {
  stroke: var(--accent-color);
  will-change: transform;
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 2.8;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  animation: progress 1s ease-out forwards;
}

.circle-bg {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: #eee;
  stroke-width: 3.8;
}


.percentage {
  fill: #666;
  font-family: 'Electrolize', sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.5em;
  text-anchor: middle;
}

@keyframes progress {
  0% {
      stroke-dasharray: 0 100;
  }
}
```

Here is the JS

```
//variables for text and stroke-dasharray
let progressSection = document.querySelector('.circular-chart');
let progressBar = document.querySelector('.circle');
let progressNum = document.querySelector('.percentage');
let progressSectionDt = document.querySelector('.circular-chart-dt');
let progressBarDt = document.querySelector('.circle-dt');
let progressNumDt = document.querySelector('.percentage-dt');

//function to change stroke value and text innerHTML into the calculated scroll percentage
function updateProgressBar(){
    progressBar.style.strokeDasharray = `${getScrollPercentage()}, 100`;
    progressBarDt.style.strokeDasharray = `${getScrollPercentage()}, 100`;
    if(Math.round(getScrollPercentage()) <= 100){
      progressNum.innerHTML = `${Math.round(getScrollPercentage())}%`;
      progressNumDt.innerHTML = `${Math.round(getScrollPercentage())}%`;
      requestAnimationFrame(updateProgressBar)
    }else {
      progressNum.innerHTML = `100%`;
      progressNumDt.innerHTML = `100%`;
      requestAnimationFrame(updateProgressBar)
  }
}

//function to return scroll position as percentage of full page height
function getScrollPercentage(){
     return ((window.scrollY) / (document.body.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight) * 100)
}

//initial recursive function call updating animations on user scroll
updateProgressBar()
```

Answer (score 0):

The svg is in a container as shown below.  That is 10px from the bottom. Can you try to change that to `top: 50%` such that it is view and fixed when the page is loaded. I think it may be the progress bar is out of view on mobile. On desktop i managed to get it when i scrolled down but initially i could not find it

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: fixed;
    right: 10px;
    bottom: 10px; // change this to `top: 50%`
    z-index: 9;
}
```